# Give MySQL users limited permissions

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

At our company, we give PHP developers Desktop User accounts... so we don't give MySQL root password for them as well. What I want to accomplish is letting the users create, see and control the databases they created only.

I checked this thread but the thing through phpMyAdmin didn't work for me at all:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=323021

Getting 3 problems:

1. The databases created by the users are not automatically prefixed with their username.
2. The user is able to delete other users' databases (I unchecked all admin column permissions.)
3. The users see all the databases where it should be hidden if they don't have their username as prefix.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

[image]

That 'Database for user' setting is the key. Make sure you don't set any of the global grants that show up right below that option set.